# Removing smooth bolt pedals?

Tags: pedals

Let me begin by saying that yes, I am trying to unscrew the pedal in the correct direction. It is the right side pedal, I am attempting to turn it counter-clockwise.

So here are the [pedals I have](http://www.nashbar.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/mProduct4_10052_10053_554739_-1_catNav):

[image]

Now, they look like they have a nice textured part that you can grip when installing or removing them. Unfortunately, that is not the case. That knobby part is actually part of the pedal. It rotates with the pedal itself.

The threaded portion of the pedal that screws into the crank is completely smooth. As in baby smooth. There's nothing for a wrench to grip. I have a pair of pliers that are just a tiny bit too wide. I'm going to see if I can find a narrower pair.

The first pedal came off easily. It just unscrewed. This one seems a bit more "stuck". Other than getting a smaller pair of pliers, are there any good tricks to removing pedals like these?

Comment: I would be concerned if you unscrew the pedal with no tools.

Comment: If you can grab the pedal with pliers and remove it with this style of pedal, chances are it was too loose.

Comment: The knobbly ring at the left side of the pedal is to remove the pedal axle from the pedal body.

Answer (score 6):

There should be a hex socket at the end of the axle, inside the crank. Use a long hex wrench to unscrew the pedal.

The textured part is for disassembling the pedal.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that as soon as I get home today. But that would make sense.